# How to get child entity ids without loading the whole child entities in TypeORM?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have the following models:

```
@Entity('user')
class UserModel {
    @PrimaryColumn({
        name: 'id',
        type: 'varchar',
    })
    id: Ulid = generate()

    ...

    @OneToMany(() => CourseModel, (course) => course.author)
    courses?: CourseModel[]
}

@Entity('course')
class CourseModel {
    @PrimaryColumn({
        name: 'id',
        type: 'varchar',
    })
    id: Ulid = generate()

    ...

    @ManyToOne(() => UserModel, (user) => user.courses)
    user?: UserModel
}
```

I need to query users and receive something like this:

```js
{
    id: '...',
    ...
    courseIds: ['...', '...', etc...]
}
```

In TypeORM I could not find any option to load `courseIds`, only `courses`. Is there an option to do so without query builder?

I tried creating a getter in User class, but it still needs to load all the users. Also I tried queryBuilder and it works, but it may be not the best solution. There must be a way to do it without query builder

Answer (score 1):

I found that @RelationId decorator is suitable for this.

Just use:

```
@OneToMany(() => CourseModel, (course) => course.author)
courses?: CourseModel[]

@RelationId((course) => course.author)
courseIds: string[]
```